# Laravel upload without form and request functionality

Tags: laravel, file, cron, scheduler

I want to run a scheduler (CRON) that reads a csv file every minute and imports it into a database.
I want to grab the file from a predefined directory on my windows directory system and upload it into the storage area in Laravel on my host server.

I created a test function to read the contents of a directory. I get an error 
'The "C:/Users/alfre/code" directory does not exist.'.

What is the correct way to upload files with a scheduler?

```
   'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],

    'odoofiles' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => '\Users\alfre\code\storage\csv',
    ],

 I could not find an answer yet on the web.
```

Answer (score 0):

you should not use absolute paths from windows.
try placing the cvs folds in in the storage folder and try
on your computer it will be something like C:/Users/alfre/code/storage/csv

```
public function test()
    {
        $files = File::allFiles(storage_path('csv'));
        foreach ($files as $file)
        {
            echo (string)$file, "\n";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. But it did not help me. I edited my question to clarify my question.